# The view is display difference on Iphone XS Max, Iphone 11 pro max with difference project

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I had one problem with display view on my project.
[attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hge3t.png)
When I create same view in xib file with size (250 x 366) on my company project and simple project so I load this xib file to show on my control by addSubView function.
When I run it on iphone xs max or iphone 11 pro max simulator this view just show differenced.

In my company project these view bigger than define size.
In my simple project these view is same with define size.

I don't know why had difference when I show these view on above two project.
does anyone know this difference can be teach for me. 
thanks you so much.

```html
<img src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/hge3t.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create view with specific constraints and you can add the UIImageView for subview or you can create constraints for UIImageView in a  wanted sizes.
In example:

```
let imgView = UIImageView()
//make constraints for width, height and top or bottom anchor. After that you can simple fill the imageView like that.
imgView.widthAnchor(equalTo: 250).isActive = true
imgView.heightAnchor(equalTo: 366).isActive = true
imgView.centerYAnchor(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

**Content Mode: ScaleAspectFill**

Scales the content to fill the size of view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But I don't know why the difference happen in my two project. 
If you know can you tell me why had these difference.